# C# Entity Framework Inheritance: Automatic Mapping a Property To Children Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was wondering if we can automatically map a property into children property when retrieving from database.

Example :

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Hash { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountProfile")]
    public Guid? AccountProfileId { get; set; }

    public virtual AccountProfile AccountProfile { get; set; }
}

public class AccountProfile
{
    [Key]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AccountAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

And then I make a view model:

```
[NotMapped]
public class AccountVM : Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; } //Map this into AccountProfile.Name
}
```

I want to auto map the `Name` into `base.AccountProfile.Name` when retrieving the data from database:

```
List<AccountVM> models = db.Accounts.Include(m => m.Roles).Include(m => m.AccountProfile).ToList();
```

This code will not work because I need to do `Select(m => new AccountVM() {...})` which is not code efficient, because I have to assign each of the properties.

So is there a way to do this?

---

### Updated

So I just figurred out a little change in my view model into:

```
[NotMapped]
public class AccountVM : Account
{
    public string Name { get { return base.AccountProfile.Name; } set { base.AccountProfile.Name = value; } }
}
```

and my retriever:

```
List<AccountVM> models = db.Accounts.Include(m => m.Roles).Include(m => m.AccountProfile).Select(m => m as AccountVM).ToList();
```

Then another error arise:

> The 'TypeAs' expression with an input of type 'Yountrep.Models.Account' and a check of type 'Yountrep.ViewModels.AccountVM' is not supported. Only entity types and complex types are supported in LINQ to Entities queries.

I guess the problem is now how to typecast it into `AccountVM`

Answer (score 1):

Your view model should not be inheriting from an entity model.  You can create your view model like this to include any relational objects.

```
public class AccountVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AccountProfile Profile { get; set; }

    public class AccountProfile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can than manually copy over the properties when building your LINQ query:

```
List<AccountVM> vm = db.Accounts.Select(a => 
{ 
    new AccountVM {
        Name= a.Name,
        Profile = new AccountProfile {
            Name = a.AccountProfile.Name
        }    
    }
}).ToList();
```

Another alternative is to use AutoMapper.  I use AutoMapper for several of my projects, and it reduces the need to have to manually translate every field.

[AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)

If you want to flatten properties:

```
    public class AccountVM
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    }

List<AccountVM> vm = db.Accounts.Select(a => 
{ 
    new AccountVM {
        Name= a.Name,
        ProfileName = (a.AccountProfile == null) ? "" : a.AccountProfile.Name
       }    
    }
}).ToList();
```

I also added a ternary expression to check for null.  This will avoid an exception error if profile does not exist.

Comment: Yes when using `Select` everything works well. Is there a way to avoid it. I want the properties from `Account` are all the same level as the properties from `AccountVM`. In your example `AccountVM` will have to assign the AccountProfile into another property which I want to avoid it.

Comment: There is difference between code efficiency and minimizing code.  When working with an n-tier architecture, the view model and entity models should be treated completely separate.  Mapping model properties is standard practice.  It allows you to take the entity model and transform it to something the client can use.  I used to try to do exactly what you are trying to do, but found that it violates Single Responsibility Principals and Separation of Concerns.